# Deserializing XML into C# class member without nesting tags

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have some xml that looks likes this:

```
<data>
    <typeadatas>
        <typea>
            <name>ExampleName1</name>
            <!-- Other tags -->
        </typea>
        <!-- And more type a data -->
    </typeadatas>
    <arrays>
        <typea>
            <name>ExampleName2</name>
            <!-- Other tags, same as tags in other <typea> tag above -->
            <dimension1>
                <!-- tags informing about the dimension -->
            </dimension1>
         </typea>
     </arrays>
</data>
```

It describes a series of variables in another program, so that tools like debuggers can understand the memory layout.

I need to get this into a series of C# classes to be able to do further processing.  Currently I have a series of classes that look like:

```
class Data : IXmlSerializable {
    /* Custom implementation of ReadXml to handle various complications in the xml not shown here */
    List<TypeA> TypeAData
    List<ArrayType<TypeA>> TypeADataInArrays
}

class BaseType {
    public string Name;
    /* Other properties */
}

class TypeA : BaseType {
}

class Dimension {
    /* Dimension properties */
}

class ArrayType<T> where T : BaseType {
    T BaseData;
    Dimension Dimension1;
}
```

There exists further data types that are stored, but share (for now) the same set of data as typea does.  Thus BaseType is used to store all the common elements.  I don't want to rely on this always being true though.

For the array information, they store data about a separate piece of data (So the typea tags are independent in the example given), but I still want to reuse the common data inside a common class for arrays for dealing with dimensions and the like.  However, in the given classes, the BaseData member never receives data from the XML deserialization process as C# expects it to be inside another tag.  However, I don't want to have another tag there, as it just makes the XML harder to understand.

Thus, besides making a custom ReadXml function for ArrayType, is there a way to have C# automatically read the tags from within the typea array element into BaseData, without having a BaseData tag?

To clarify, I'd like to be able to run the following with an XmlReader pointing at the typea tag in the arrays tag:

```
ArrayType<TypeA> theData;
XmlSerializer xmlS = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayType<TypeA>));
theData = (ArrayType<TypeA>)xmlS.Deserialize(reader);
```

And have all the data available in that tag available.  The Dimension1 field is filled out right now, but that BaseData field is left blank, as C# expects a BaseData tag in the xml, where none exist.  Preferably without change the Xml, I need to get the data available to me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? Your last paragraph is missing some information I think.

Comment: Oops, didn't proof read it closely enough.  Basically, I'd like to be able to deserialize a typea element in an arrays element into an ArrayType<TypeA>, without writing a custom ReadXml function.  I'm not sure if C# allows this though.  Updated question to try and explain that.

Comment: The third-last C# line, "T BaseData", should that maybe be "T[] BaseData;"? And I'm finding it very hard to understand what you're doing. It might help if you provided a real XML sample, without the vague placeholders like "Some data of type a" and "<!-- Other tags -->" and "Array of data using a type a", etc.

Comment: Regarding the code, It isn't an array, but it was missing a semicolon.  I've update the question with some information about the Xml format, along with how I want to read in the Xml data.  The format describes a series of variables (some of which may be arrays).  So the array id described by the base data and the information about the dimensions.  I can't provide a real example due to company policies, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Why would `ArrayType<T>` even use generics? Shouldn't it just be a subclass of `BaseType` or `TypeA`? That way your `ArrayType` would get it's own `Dimension` populated, as well as the `Name` and others from its base class.

Now, that object model above is quite confusing (probably also from the fact that what it actually represents is obfuscated).

What I commonly do, when having to work with odd XML structures, is just extract the XSD from the XML and try to see what the auto-generated C# classes would look like.
Even if it's not ideal for later use, you can use it to read the info into it, and then, populate whatever object model you actually want from the data in the auto-generated objects.

There are also a few online tools if you are not familiar with XSD.exe, such as:

http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output

That one generated the following XSD schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="typeadatas">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>And more type a data</xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="typea">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:documentation>Other tags</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="arrays">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="typea">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dimension1">
                      <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Other tags, same as tags in other &lt;typea> tag above  tags informing about the dimension</xs:documentation>
                      </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And throwing that Schema to this site: http://www.httputility.net/xsd-to-csharp-vb-class.aspx you can get a more standard C# class definition that would be able to read it.

That way you use the auto-generated code as just a way to facilitate the reading, but can later iterate, evaluate, and populate your own complex model from it.

I think trying to mix odd xml with complex object models directly can lead to quite a few headaches (not to mention how highly coupled they end up).

Comment: Regarding your question, it uses generics so that if TypeA has further properties in the future, ArrayType will have access to them only when it references TypeA things.  There are other types allowed (call them TypeB/TypeC), and some of them do have extra properties, but all of them need to work as an ArrayType.  If this was C++, I'd just inherit from the templated type.  While I did obfuscate the names, the structure is still the same.

Comment: As for your suggestion, I took the we've built XSD for the document and generated the classes.  It looks pretty straight forward.  I'm not sure using that (+ a conversion inside of the project) instead of just implementing ReadXml myself is better.  Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well, if the generated classes can cover your entire model, I'd probably go with that, just mainly based on convenience. However, if your structure could be extremely dynamic and you prefer to have full control over how each node is read, then coding your own could be an option.
Another option could be using Linq to XML directly and not even worry about the model, and just handle XElements http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx